# Calculator Program Xcode Error Expected expression before '@' token

Tags: c++, xcode, variables, calculator, cs193p

I'm doing the Stanford xcode class CS193P assignment #2 and I'm getting some errors.  The tasks is to write a calculator program with variables. I am using Xcode 3.2.6  www.stanford.edu/class/.../Assignment%202_1.pdf

I'm getting the error Expected expression before '@' token when I am declaring vp

```
#define VARIABLE_PREFIX @“%”


- (void)setVariableAsOperand:(NSString *)variableName
{
    NSString *vp = VARIABLE_PREFIX; (error is on this line) 
    NSString *variable = [vp stringByAppendingString:variableName];
    [self addObjectToExpression:variable];  
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Message me if you have any questions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is that a verbatim copy of your code? Those quotes look like the wrong kind.

Comment: Sure this is meant to be c++ code?!?

Comment: @Biffen Yes that was a verbatim copy. I just deleted the quotes and retyped them now and it solved my problem. Thanks! I wonder how I got the wrong quotes

Answer (score -1):

Quotes in C++ have to be of the right kind, i.e. `"` (U+0022, QUOTATION MARK). Some applications (read: not proper text editors) will convert typed quotes into ‘fancy’ ones, e.g. `“` (U+201C, LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) and `”` (U+201D, RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK).

Watch out for copying code via a word processor, e-mail composer, etc. And if you need to examine a character your text editor of choice might be able to do it (I know Emacs can), or you can use tools like [this one](http://rishida.net/uniview/).